# How to maintain UIView ratio across different devices using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have one `UIView` in `LaunchScreen`.

[image]

I have added following constraint to this `UIView`.

[image]

I want my red view always `35%` of the screen.

I have calculated the height of `RedView` as : My `ViewController` height is `667` I calculated the `35%` and assigned to `RedView`.

I want to know that is my approach is correct. As their is very slight change in width of `iPhone6Plus` and huge change in height.

> Is my constraint correct for 35:65 screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of giving Aspect ratio you could also give it a multiplier for 35%.

**Step 1:**
Pin `RedView` from 3 sides, `Right-Top-Left`

**Step 2:**
Make `RedView` and ViewController's main view to Equal height.

**Step 3:**
Select `RedView's` equal height constraint and go to it's attribute inspector. (4th right tab)

**Step 4:**
Change `Multiplier` value to `0.35`.

Now RedView will be always `35%` of your main screen in both Orientations.

[image: 35% always]

Comment: thanks....  I tried this is working fine...Will my solution works ? or their is any issue in it.

Comment: Try changing orientation of your view in storyboard or preview, you'll get your answer.